# zooming a selected part of image with cursor event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/JDU9f/1/

what I want is when the user do a selection the selected part is zoomed in .Is there anyway to achieve this ?

this is the code so far :

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        w = canvas.width,
        h = canvas.height,
        x1,
        y1,
        isDown = false;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://www.stockfreeimages.com/static/homepage/female-chaffinch-free-stock-photo-106202.jpg";
    canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        x1 = e.clientX - rect.left;
        y1 = e.clientY - rect.top;
        isDown = true;
    }
    canvas.onmouseup = function () {
        isDown = false;
    }
    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {

        if (!isDown) return;

        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
            x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
            y2 = e.clientY - rect.top;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.strokeRect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    }

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    };
```

I can make the selection but how can i zoom the selected part only ? like this example : http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/zooming-panning/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'zoom the selected part only'? You only want to see the part you selected, zoomed in? Or do you also still want to see the rest of the image not zoomed in?

Comment: i just want to see the selected part zoomed in by a pre-defiend scale

Comment: I have tried something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JDU9f/3/). Please check it.

Comment: the first selection is exactly what i want to achieve but when i try to do a second selection there is a problem :/

Comment: How would you like to reset the zoomed state?

Comment: onmouseMove i suppose

Comment: Check this updated link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JDU9f/5/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55710/discussion-between-rohith-and-sora).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those looking for zooming functionality *without the use of a canvas*, here's a pretty foolproof solution using a simple `<img />`:

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {
  //VARS===================================================
  var zoom = {
    zoomboxLeft:null, zoomboxTop:null, //zoombox
    cursorStartX:null, cursorStartY:null, //cursor
    imgStartLeft:null, imgStartTop:null, //image
    minDragLeft:null,maxDragLeft:null, minDragTop:null,maxDragTop:null
  };
  
  //KEY-HANDLERS===========================================
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which==32) {e.preventDefault(); if (!$(".zoombox img").hasClass("moving")) {$(".zoombox img").addClass("drag");}} //SPACE
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which==32) {if (!$(".zoombox img").hasClass("moving")) {$(".zoombox img").removeClass("drag");}} //SPACE
  });
  
  //RESET IMAGE SIZE=======================================
  $(".reset").on("click",function() {
    var zoombox = "#"+$(this).parent().attr("id")+" .zoombox";
    $(zoombox+" img").css({"left":0, "top":0, "width":$(zoombox).width(), "height":$(zoombox).height()});
  }).click();
  
  //ZOOM&DRAG-EVENTS=======================================
  //MOUSEDOWN----------------------------------------------
  $(".zoombox img").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".zoombox img").addClass("moving");
    var selector = $(this).next();
    var zoombox = $(this).parent();
    $(zoombox).addClass("active");
    
    //store zoombox left&top
    zoom.zoomboxLeft = $(zoombox).offset().left + parseInt($(zoombox).css("border-left-width").replace(/\D+/,""));
    zoom.zoomboxTop = $(zoombox).offset().top + parseInt($(zoombox).css("border-top-width").replace(/\D+/,""));
    
    //store starting positions of cursor (relative to zoombox)
    zoom.cursorStartX = e.pageX - zoom.zoomboxLeft;
    zoom.cursorStartY = e.pageY - zoom.zoomboxTop;
    
    if ($(".zoombox img").hasClass("drag")) {
      //store starting positions of image (relative to zoombox)
      zoom.imgStartLeft = $(this).position().left;
      zoom.imgStartTop = $(this).position().top;
      
      //set drag boundaries (relative to zoombox)
      zoom.minDragLeft = $(zoombox).width() - $(this).width();
      zoom.maxDragLeft = 0;
      zoom.minDragTop = $(zoombox).height() - $(this).height();
      zoom.maxDragTop = 0;
    } else {
      //set drag boundaries (relative to zoombox)
      zoom.minDragLeft = 0;
      zoom.maxDragLeft = $(zoombox).width();
      zoom.minDragTop = 0;
      zoom.maxDragTop = $(zoombox).height();
      
      //activate zoom-selector
      $(selector).css({"display":"block", "width":0, "height":0, "left":zoom.cursorStartX, "top":zoom.cursorStartY});
    }
  });
  
  //MOUSEMOVE----------------------------------------------
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if ($(".zoombox img").hasClass("moving")) {
      if ($(".zoombox img").hasClass("drag")) {
        var img = $(".zoombox.active img")[0];
        
        //update image position (relative to zoombox)
        $(img).css({
          "left": zoom.imgStartLeft + (e.pageX-zoom.zoomboxLeft)-zoom.cursorStartX,
          "top": zoom.imgStartTop + (e.pageY-zoom.zoomboxTop)-zoom.cursorStartY
        });
        //prevent dragging in prohibited areas (relative to zoombox)
        if ($(img).position().left <= zoom.minDragLeft) {$(img).css("left",zoom.minDragLeft);} else 
        if ($(img).position().left >= zoom.maxDragLeft) {$(img).css("left",zoom.maxDragLeft);}
        if ($(img).position().top <= zoom.minDragTop) {$(img).css("top",zoom.minDragTop);} else 
        if ($(img).position().top >= zoom.maxDragTop) {$(img).css("top",zoom.maxDragTop);}
      } else {
        //calculate selector width and height (relative to zoombox)
        var width = (e.pageX-zoom.zoomboxLeft)-zoom.cursorStartX;
        var height = (e.pageY-zoom.zoomboxTop)-zoom.cursorStartY;
        
        //prevent dragging in prohibited areas (relative to zoombox)
        if (e.pageX-zoom.zoomboxLeft <= zoom.minDragLeft) {width = zoom.minDragLeft - zoom.cursorStartX;} else 
        if (e.pageX-zoom.zoomboxLeft >= zoom.maxDragLeft) {width = zoom.maxDragLeft - zoom.cursorStartX;}
        if (e.pageY-zoom.zoomboxTop <= zoom.minDragTop) {height = zoom.minDragTop - zoom.cursorStartY;} else 
        if (e.pageY-zoom.zoomboxTop >= zoom.maxDragTop) {height = zoom.maxDragTop - zoom.cursorStartY;}
        
        //update zoom-selector
        var selector = $(".zoombox.active .selector")[0];
        $(selector).css({"width":Math.abs(width), "height":Math.abs(height)});
        if (width<0) {$(selector).css("left",zoom.cursorStartX-Math.abs(width));}
        if (height<0) {$(selector).css("top",zoom.cursorStartY-Math.abs(height));}
      }
    }
  });
  
  //MOUSEUP------------------------------------------------
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    if ($(".zoombox img").hasClass("moving")) {
      if (!$(".zoombox img").hasClass("drag")) {
        var img = $(".zoombox.active img")[0];
        var selector = $(".zoombox.active .selector")[0];
        
        if ($(selector).width()>0 && $(selector).height()>0) {
          //resize zoom-selector and image
          var magnification = ($(selector).width()<$(selector).height() ? $(selector).parent().width()/$(selector).width() : $(selector).parent().height()/$(selector).height()); //go for the highest magnification
          var hFactor = $(img).width() / ($(selector).position().left-$(img).position().left);
          var vFactor = $(img).height() / ($(selector).position().top-$(img).position().top);
          $(selector).css({"width":$(selector).width()*magnification, "height":$(selector).height()*magnification});
          $(img).css({"width":$(img).width()*magnification, "height":$(img).height()*magnification});
          //correct for misalignment during magnification, caused by size-factor
          $(img).css({
            "left": $(selector).position().left - ($(img).width()/hFactor),
            "top": $(selector).position().top - ($(img).height()/vFactor)
          });
          
          //reposition zoom-selector and image (relative to zoombox)
          var selectorLeft = ($(selector).parent().width()/2) - ($(selector).width()/2);
          var selectorTop = ($(selector).parent().height()/2) - ($(selector).height()/2);
          var selectorDeltaLeft = selectorLeft - $(selector).position().left;
          var selectorDeltaTop = selectorTop - $(selector).position().top;
          $(selector).css({"left":selectorLeft, "top":selectorTop});
          $(img).css({"left":"+="+selectorDeltaLeft, "top":"+="+selectorDeltaTop});
        }
        //deactivate zoom-selector
        $(selector).css({"display":"none", "width":0, "height":0, "left":0, "top":0});
      } else {$(".zoombox img").removeClass("drag");}
      $(".zoombox img").removeClass("moving");
      $(".zoombox.active").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*CONTAINER-------------------*/
#container {
  width: 234px;
  height: 199px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/*ZOOMBOX=====================*/
/*IMAGE-----------------------*/
.zoombox {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
  background-color: #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.zoombox img {position:relative;}
.zoombox img.drag {cursor:move;}
.zoombox .selector {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
}
/*CONTROL---------------------*/
.reset {float:left;}
.info {float:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!--ZOOMBOX-->
  <div class="zoombox">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/colors/img_colormap.gif" />
    <div class="selector"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="reset" value="Reset" /><span class="info">Press SPACE to drag</span>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nt8k8e6/**

- The `container` element can be anything, just place the `.zoombox` on your webpage and it should work.
- You should even be able to put multiple `.zoombox`es next to each other in the same container-element. I haven't tested it though.

It's not too complicated, there's not a whole lot of comments, but the variable names are pretty self-explanatory and make the code easy enough to read, and all the jquery-functions can be looked up.

The code is essentially divided into three handlers: `.mousedown()`, `.mousemove()`, `.mouseup()`.
 - In `mousedown` some values are stored into variables (like the start-coordinates for the selector), which are used in `mousemove` and `mouseup` as a reference.

If you want to know exactly what's happening, just have a look at the code, as I said it's not too difficult.

Comment: Hi How we can do rotation of this image and zoom will work for same after rotation?

Comment: @ArjunMandloi While `.zoombox img {transform:rotate(20deg);}` will rotate the image, zooming the rotated image is unfortunately not as simple, and the zoomed result will be off from your selection. You might be able to correct this by reversing the rotation inside the calculations, but where exactly you would need to do that, and how you would have to correct the placement of the rotated image afterwards so that it lines up correctly with the zoombox, I don't know... I think in this case you might be better off using a canvas.