# How to select a particular area of image in angular js with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have an idea to implement something like this.[image]

There is a **small image down and on hovering** i need to be able to **select some particular area and display that portion of image in zoomed format** with the scroll bar. That enables user to see the whole image. I googled for the zoomer and got lots of plugins in JQuery. *But i think they are not suitable for my requirement*. I need suggestions for how to achieve the end result.My technology stack is angular js.

Comment: [Maybe this will help you in some way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40479501/3407923). There is some jQuery in there, but I'm pretty sure that can all be rewritten to pure JS or AngularJS or whatever.

Comment: Yeah that's fine but in your case you are providing zoom in the same image. In my case i want that small image to be static and on selection of some area (may be hover) i need to display the whole image in upper canvas(with zoomed) and the functionality to scroll the whole image. I think i need some css and canvas. I'll start and put the plnkr link here.